# Can't get these javascript if statements to work

Tags: javascript, jquery

[JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jtree5757/suqqU/8/)

**JS**

```
var rangesliderfilter = function () {
    var low = parseInt(jQuery('#min-value-span').text());
    var high = parseInt(jQuery('#max-value-span').text());
    var BreakfastDR = [];
    var LunchDR = [];
    var DinnerDR = [];
    var SnacksDR = [];
    var TheString = [];
    var TestSlider = [];
    while (low <= high) {
        BreakfastDR.push('.' + low +'.breakfast');
        LunchDR.push('.' + low +'.lunch');
        DinnerDR.push('.' + low +'.dinner');
        SnacksDR.push('.' + low +'.snacks');
        TestSlider.push('.'+low);
        low++;
    }

    var checkbox1 = jQuery('.checkbox1').prop(':checked');
    var checkbox2 = jQuery('.checkbox2').prop(':checked');
    var checkbox3 = jQuery('.checkbox3').prop(':checked');
    var checkbox4 = jQuery('.checkbox4').prop(':checked');

     if (checkbox1){
        TheString.push(BreakfastDR)
    }
     if (checkbox2){
        TheString.push(LunchDR)
    }
     if (checkbox3){
        TheString.push(DinnerDR)
    }
     if (checkbox4){
        TheString.push(SnacksDR)
    }

    jQuery('.rangecheck').attr('value', TheString);
}
```

**HTML**

```
<fieldset>
     <h4>Meal Time</h4>

    <div class="checkbox">
        <input type="checkbox" value=".breakfast" class="checkbox1" />
        <label>Breakfast</label>
    </div>
    <div class="checkbox">
        <input type="checkbox" value=".lunch" class="checkbox2" />
        <label>Lunch</label>
    </div>
    <div class="checkbox">
        <input type="checkbox" value=".dinner" class="checkbox3" />
        <label>Dinner</label>
    </div>
    <div class="checkbox">
        <input type="checkbox" value=".snacks" class="checkbox4" />
        <label>Snacks</label>
    </div>
</fieldset>
```

To see how the string should be just go to line 176 in the fiddle and change `TheString` to `BreakfastDR`. See console.log for the string output. That is how it is supposed to look like when checkbox1 is checked and the range slider is active.

Also, if you change line 176 to `jQuery('.rangecheck').attr('value', BreakfastDr + LunchDR + DinnerDR + SnacksDR);` the console wil show you what it is suppose to look like if all 4 checkboxes were checked and range slider active.

But my problem is that the array is not being built. The `.push()` method works fine, it is in the `if` statement where the problem is. (try deleting the `if` parts and just have the `.push()` parts to see what I mean)

Can someone correct my mistake here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The prop string should be without the colon like this:

```
var checkbox1 = jQuery('.checkbox1').prop('checked');
```

Answer (score 0):

try to use method attr instead of prop like this:

```
var checkbox1 = jQuery('.checkbox1').attr(':checked');
var checkbox2 = jQuery('.checkbox2').attr(':checked');
var checkbox3 = jQuery('.checkbox3').attr(':checked');
var checkbox4 = jQuery('.checkbox4').attr(':checked');
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
var checkbox1 = $(".checkbox1").is(':checked')
var checkbox2 = $(".checkbox2").is(':checked')
var checkbox3 = $(".checkbox3").is(':checked')
var checkbox4 = $(".checkbox4").is(':checked')
```

refer link [check checkbox is checked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/901712/check-checkbox-checked-property-using-jquery)